# Wordpress theme and plugin upload disabled, theme editor disabled as well

Tags: php, wordpress, sftp

I'm developing an old wordpress website. There I can not upload any theme/plugin. I mean there's no `add new` option for plugins and themes. I updated it to the latest 4.7.1 version but still no luck. In `config.php` file there's no `DISALLOW_FILE_MODS` or `DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT` such option defined. I can't figure out where this disable option came from?

Also it's uploaded on a sftp server. I can manually upload any plugin to wp-content/plugins folder through sftp but after activating the plugin it makes the website frontend white screen death.

Overall, how could I allow theme,plugin uploading or how could I allow `add new` options to them?

Comment: - You have checked may be it disable through css mean using style make display none ?.

Answer (score 0):

Reading around the web about this, it seems like this might be caused by not having enough resources to operate, so I assume WordPress checks for this and disables in advance the ability to add new content.

I suggest checking the following values in the php.ini config file (you can run a script containing `<?php phpinfo() ?>` from the server to see the values faster; just don't make it publicly accessible):

- `display_memory` - should be at least 128M
- `max_post_size` - by default is 8M, try setting it to 128
- `upload_max_filesize` - by default is 2M, try setting it to 128